# How does one control whitespace around a figure in matplotlib?(plt.tight_layout does not work)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a matplotlib figure with 3 sub-plots. The consensus from stackexchange seems to be to use the plt.tight_layout in order to get rid of the whitespace around the figure. This does not solve the problem in my case.

My code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

my_dpi = 1500
plt.ion()

index = np.linspace(0,5,10)
combined = np.linspace(0,1,10)
case1 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
case2 = np.linspace(0,1,10)
case3 = np.linspace(0,1,10)

tsfont = {'fontname':'Times-Roman'}
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 18})
mpl.rc('font',family='Arial')
ms = 0

f = plt.figure()
f.set_size_inches(7.5,10)
f.axison=False


lw = 2
asp = 5


axarr1 = plt.subplot(3,1,1, adjustable='box',aspect = asp)

axarr1.set_xlim(0,5,10)
axarr1.set_ylim(0,1)
axarr1.set_ylabel('y')
axarr1.set_xlabel('$\\tau$', fontsize =25)
p = axarr1.plot(index,combined,color='navy', linewidth=lw, label = "Healthy")
axarr1.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.05)


'''
Duct 2
'''

axarr2 = plt.subplot(3,1,2, adjustable='box',aspect = asp)
#axarr2.set_aspect('auto')
axarr2.set_xlim(0,5,10)
axarr2.set_ylim(0,1)
axarr2.set_ylabel('y')
axarr2.set_xlabel('$\\tau$', fontsize = 25)
g = axarr2.plot(index,combined,color='navy', linewidth=lw)
axarr2.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.05)

'''
Duct 3
'''

axarr3 = plt.subplot(3,1,3, adjustable='box',aspect = asp)

axarr3.set_xlim(0,5,10)
axarr3.set_ylim(0,1)
axarr3.set_ylabel('y')
axarr3.set_xlabel('$\\tau$', fontsize = 25)
w = axarr3.plot(index,combined,color='navy', linewidth=lw)
axarr3.xaxis.set_label_coords(0.5, -0.05)

#plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Without using plt.tight_layout() I get the following result

[image]

Uncommenting the relevant line gives me

[image: As is obvious, while the vertical spacing changes, the horizontal spacing does not]

As is obvious, while the vertical spacing changes, the horizontal spacing does not

I'd like to know how to get rid of the horizontal whitespacing to the left and right.

Comment: How about adjusting the figure size, it seems you want to reduce the width of your figure window.  
f = plt.figure(figsize=(3.5, 10)).
Not sure if you need this one  =>  # f.set_size_inches(7.5,10).

Are you saving the figure?

Answer (score 0):

The `tight_layout` option places the images closer to the borders. However, in your case, there is nothing to fill this empty space with, so it doesn't work.

If you want a narrower figure, you should change the horizontal dimension, e.g.:

```
plt.figure(..., tight_layout=True, figsize=(12, 5))
```

This is in inches, experiment with the numbers until it looks good.

You could also use 2 by 2 subplots to keep a square figure and use the space better:

```
plt.subplot(2, 2, ...)
```

although this may look suboptimal with a prime number of figures.

Comment: I get an error if I try to include the tight_layout argument in the plt.subplot function. It works without error if I include it in the original f.plot() but doesn't solve the problem. I guess I have to work with the figure size itself

Comment: fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,n, sharex=True, sharey=True, tight_layout=True)  is what I use for horizontally located subplots.  In this case n is the number of subplots and tight_layout helps if you get the page width correct

Comment: Ow yeah, the parameters are for `subplots`/`figure` not `subplot`, sorry for that. Anyway the essential part is the `figsize` if you want to change the aspect ratio of the figure; tight layout only won't cut it.